# Querying an array with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, filtering, lodash

Given this array of accounts (a sample of an array which contains 500,000+ records)

```
    {
      "Accounts": {
        "Account": [
          {
          "AccountNo":"12345",
          "Status":"Active",
          "Type":"Supplier",
          "Account":"Big tile company",
          "PermissionForSales":"Granted",
          "Orders":{
             "OrderDetail":[{
                "Date":"2018-09-05",
                "OrderID":"Abc121"
             },
             {
                "Date":"2018-04-09",
                "OrderID":"Nmp9812"
             }]
          }
       },
       {
          "AccountNo":"98765",
          "Status":"Inactive",
          "Type":"Supplier",
          "Account":"Boxes Inc",
          "PermissionForSales":"Granted",
          "Orders":{
             "OrderDetail":[{
                "Date":"2018-10-11",
                "OrderID":"Yrt172"
             },
             {
                "Date":"2018-04-01",
                "OrderID":"Hwr121"
             }]
          }
       }
    ]}}
```

A user can query the following fields in any combination: AccountNo, Status, Account and OrderID

Now, I can quite happily filter based on one field in the top level:

```
var result = _.filter(accounts, function (a) {
  return (a.Account.toLowerCase().indexOf((query).toLowerCase()) !== -1)
});
```

So if someone searches for "Big" I'll get a new array with just the first entry of the example as the Account contains the word "Big"

However, How do I amend this filter to include the other fields (case insensitive is a must) and return a new array of all matching accounts where any combination of results have been found.

Eg:

- If someone were to search for OrderID "121" I'd expect both records back
- If someone were to search for Account "Big" I'd expect the first record back
- If someone were to search for Account "Box" I'd expect the second record back
- If someone were to search for Account "B" and OrderID "444" I'd expect both back as B is in the Account field.

Additionally, just to make it more complicated, there may be instances where no orders exist.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `generic` and `recursive` search function that in this case is limited to your specific fields. It actually flattens the object and searches on all fields and returns the hits as paths. We simply convert the paths back to objects on the end. The only use of lodash here is the `_.get` to get the object from a given path but you can easily get a ES6 approach to that as well:

```js
let obj = { "Accounts": { "Account": [{ "AccountNo": "12345", "Status": "Active", "Type": "Supplier", "Account": "Big tile company", "PermissionForSales": "Granted", "Orders": { "OrderDetail": [{ "Date": "2018-09-05", "OrderID": "Abc121" }, { "Date": "2018-04-09", "OrderID": "Nmp9812" } ] } }, { "AccountNo": "98765", "Status": "Inactive", "Type": "Supplier", "Account": "Boxes Inc", "PermissionForSales": "Granted", "Orders": { "OrderDetail": [{ "Date": "2018-10-11", "OrderID": "Yrt172" }, { "Date": "2018-04-01", "OrderID": "Hwr121" } ] } } ] } }

const search = (obj, text, fields=['AccountNo','Status','Account','OrderID']) => {
  let hits = []
  const flatSearch = (obj, text='', hits=[], arr=[], path=null) => 
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if(typeof value == 'object')
 flatSearch(value, text, hits, arr, path ? `${path}.${key}` : key) 
      else
 if(fields.includes(key) && value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()))
    hits.push([...path.split('.'), key])
  })    
  flatSearch(obj, text, hits)
  return { Accounts: { Account: [...new Set(hits.map(x => x.slice(0,3).join('-')))].map(x=> _.get(obj, x.split('-')))}}
}

console.log(search(obj, '121'))  // both records
console.log(search(obj, 'Big'))  // only the first one
console.log(search(obj, 'Box'))  // only the second one
console.log(search(obj, 'B'))    // both records
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this searches based on what I'm after, but I need the resulting array to be the same structure as the source. This returns back an array of just the found values rather than the full account structure where matches have been identified.

Comment: Updated. Now same object is returned/constructed.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your other parameters using OR in return statement.

The example below will satisfy all your cases.

```
var result = _.filter(accounts, function (a) {
  return (a.Account.toLowerCase().indexOf((query).toLowerCase()) !== -1 || a.Orders.OrderDetail.filter((ele)=>{if(Your query) return true; })[0]
)});
```

```
a.Orders.OrderDetail.filter((ele)=>{if(Your query) return true; })[0]
```

this line is used to match your query in Orders.
I have returned true as soon as i find the element and as filter returns an array hence I used [0] to get its first element.

Comment: Of course, ok, so I've got a list of Or's for the AccountNo, Account and Status, how do I then filter the sub orders array? Is that another filter within the filter?